# Guaranteed delivery in SignalR

Tags: signalr

I'm evaluating SignalR for a medium-load web application.

We're expecting ~500 msgs / sec, which shouldn't be a problem with SignalR.

However, we're worried about the reliability of this solution. Our environment has a problematic network, and it's not rare for a client to lose its network connection for ~30 secs. Is there any mechanism to ensure that once the client reconnects, it gets all the messages that were sent during its offline time?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking for 100% guaranteed delivery, SignalR is not a good candidate for your solution. You need a robust queuing system.

Comment: You should consider RabbitMQ (http://www.rabbitmq.com/). You can queue up messages on the queue for each client even while the client is not available to pull messages from it.

Comment: +1 EkoostikMartin. If you're looking for reliable messaging you need to layer that on top of using SignalR.

Comment: I totally agree with the above comments. As a workaround you can save messages in a database and when you realize that client receive message flag them as received. Else when client reconnects push all the unreceived messages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One fairly easy way to handle this would be to assign each message an ID that increments with each message. The client would need to keep track of the latest message that he'd received, and upon reconnection would just send that message ID to the server; and the server would then need to send all the missed messages down to the client. Should be reasonably simple to implement.

EDIT: 
I don't think you'd have to maintain any real state on the server proper - I think almost all of it could get pushed out to your datastore or to your client.  The client would send up the ID or timestamp of the last message that it had received:

`$.connection.myHub.server.updateMe(lastMessageId);`

You'd want some sort of backing datastore - so when the server receives the `updateMe()` message, it would do a query on the database and pull out all the rows with an ID greater than the one it just received. It would return those to the client as part of the return value of its `UpdateMe()` method. And then it would try to deliver any new messages that come along the same way it normally would, by calling methods on the client.

As for statelessness being a goal of SignalR: I can't comment on that, beyond observing that I can't imagine any reasonably complex real-world application that wouldn't need to do have some sort of backing datastore, whether it's on SignalR or some other framework (WCF, XSockets, etc.) makes little difference.

Comment: How can you implement this using SignalR? And also, this will force me to have a state on the server, which will miss one of SignalR goals, to be a stateless fw.

Comment: @ml123 did you end up using SignalR? Is it working well? Tks

Comment: @Pascal - I'm not using SignalR on my current project, but I did use it extensively for a year or two, and found that it met my needs well. My only complaint at the time was that I disliked the fact that it used `dynamic` objects all the way through, which I thought was weird as hell for a C#-based project. Certainly it's not the way that I would have designed it.

Comment: @KenSmith Tks for the feedback

Comment: I don't understand how to implement this approach on continous message delivery. While the message delivery proceeding, client calls `updateMe` at the same time, in this case, there might be duplicate messages arriving.

Answer (score 3):

You could ofcourse use some kind of queing framework but to achive this with minimum effort you can do it like this...

Serverside: http://pastebin.com/tuicQYGq
Clientside: http://pastebin.com/a8EbusuG

I am using XSockets.NET that is a realtime communication platform (since 2009) and the controllers in XSockets.NET have state so this is easy to do.

EDIT: Ohh... to test this use two browsers for example chrome and safari, then disconnect one browser... send some messages from the other then reconnect to see the messages appear. You have to use two different browsers on localhost since xsockets will give each browser a unique storage-id.

EDIT: Added Func to the queue so that you can target specific clients even if they are offline. Now only clients matching conditions will get messages if you want to.

Regards
Uffe